Interpretation and Analysis of a Multivariate Threshold Autoregressive Model
I'm looking to study the asymmetric affect a market rate, like the Fed Funds rate has on an interest rate. In other words, I would like to study the response of interest rate adjustments in different market rate environments -- rising federal fund rate environment and falling federal fund rate environment. My dependent variable is a single interest rate and my independent variable is the federal funds rate. I wanted to explore using a multivariate threshold autoregressive model. I chose this model because I can capture the nonlinear relationships between variables via modeling their regimes. Also, I believe this model allows for clear interpretation of the model results.
I setup this model in R, using the TVAR function within the tsDyn package. After taking the first difference of both variables I ran the model, the results are below. I've looked through the documentation but couldn't find an actual definition for which set of equations belong to which side of the threshold but based on the results I can assume the first set is the side that is greater than the threshold and the second set is lesser than the threshold. My question is whether my interpretation of these results are correct. Based on the regression results, I added up the coefficients for dFedFunds within the equation dIntRate and I interpret the sum of the coefficients as the interest rate's adjustment in response to a change in the fed funds rate. For set 1 that number is .71 and for set 2 that number is .25. This essentially means in rising fed funds environments, interest rate adjustments are much more likely to be adjusted quickly (.71) rather than in a falling rate fed funds environment the adjustment is much slower (.25). Is my interpretation of these coefficients, correct?
Model TVAR with  1  thresholds

Full sample size: 240   End sample size: 234
Number of variables: 2  Number of estimated parameters: 52 + 1
AIC -6397.454   BIC -6214.322    SSR 0.0004651241 

[[1]]
                   Intercept        dIntRate -1     dFedFunds -1      dIntRate -2      dFedFunds -2     dIntRate -3      dFedFunds -3   
Equation dIntRate  0.0001(0.0003)   0.1103(0.1676)  0.3872(0.0981)*** -0.0772(0.1626)  0.1174(0.0818)   -0.1248(0.1414)  0.0741(0.0867) 
Equation dFedFunds -0.0003(0.0003)  0.3383(0.2037). 0.1786(0.1192)    -0.2581(0.1975)  -0.0892(0.0994)  -0.0723(0.1718)  0.0030(0.1053) 
                   dIntRate -4      dFedFunds -4     dIntRate -5      dFedFunds -5      dIntRate -6      dFedFunds -6    
Equation dIntRate  -0.0047(0.1439)  -0.1076(0.1048)  0.0945(0.1338)   0.5039(0.2227)*   0.2175(0.1696)   -0.2611(0.2493) 
Equation dFedFunds -0.1882(0.1749)  -0.0835(0.1273)  -0.2987(0.1626). 1.1127(0.2706)*** -0.3076(0.2060)  0.7855(0.3029)* 

[[2]]
                   Intercept          dIntRate -1      dFedFunds -1      dIntRate -2      dFedFunds -2    dIntRate -3      dFedFunds -3     
Equation dIntRate   3.6e-05(7.9e-05)  -0.0311(0.0906)  0.0601(0.0778)    0.1203(0.0808)   0.2373(0.1035)* 0.1788(0.0831)*  0.0759(0.1015)   
Equation dFedFunds -8.3e-06(9.6e-05)  -0.0037(0.1101)  0.6435(0.0945)*** -0.1158(0.0982)  0.0259(0.1258)  -0.0880(0.1010)  0.4964(0.1234)***
                   dIntRate -4      dFedFunds -4     dIntRate -5     dFedFunds -5     dIntRate -6     dFedFunds -6    
Equation dIntRate  -0.1564(0.0848). 0.0244(0.0867)   0.0985(0.0895)  -0.0460(0.0696)  0.0505(0.0753)  0.0497(0.0622)  
Equation dFedFunds -0.2375(0.1031)* -0.2602(0.1054)* 0.1008(0.1088)  0.1491(0.0846).  0.1282(0.0916)  -0.0095(0.0756) 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Threshold value: -5e-04
Percentage of Observations in each regime: 17.5% 82.5% 

